# Any recommendations for how to start a for loop using arcpy intersect between files in geodatabase?

Tags: python, for-loop, arcgis

I'm a struggling python newbie. Could you help me build a for loop to intersect files in geodatabase?

In my geodatabase I have 9 feature classes:

1. regionA_point1
2. regionA_polygon
3. regionA_line
4. regionB_point1
5. regionB_polygon
6. regionB_line
7. regionC_point1
8. regionC_polygon
9. regionC_line

and I want to loop below

```
import arcpy
import os
arcpy.env.workspace = str(mygeodatabase)

for file in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_type='ALL'):

#(pseudocode)intersect each polygon with each point if 
#they are same region (either region A, B or C)

#(pseudocode)buffer lines then intersect each line 
#with each point if they are same region 
#(either region A, B or C)
```

How can I make this loop work?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to loop through each feature class, you want to loop by region.

Expanding on your pseudocode...

```py
region_list = ['regionA', 'regionB', 'regionC']

for region in region_list:
    polygon =  '{}_polygon'.format(region)
    point = '{}_point1'.format(region)
    line = '{}_line'.format(region)

    # intersect polygon with point
    arcpy.Intersect_analysis([polygon, point], output1)

    # intersect buffered line with point
    buffered_line = arcpy.Buffer_analysis(line, 'in_memory\bufferedline', '50 Feet')
    arcpy.Intersect_analysis([buffered_line, point], output2)
```